# GPG on Ubuntu not responding

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnupg

I'm trying for the first time to use gpg to encrypt a file with a symmetric key, but gpg doesn't seem to respond when I use the `-c` switch.

`gpg -v -c filename`

.. just doesn't seem to do anything, nor to report any error, and just hangs until I hit ctrl-c.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have DISPLAY variable set it may be used to display prompt for password in a dialog window (it may have not appeared if you have DISPLAY set to some weird value). To verify that unset the variable:

```
unset DISPLAY
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be timing out checking for the gpg-agent.  I have trouble with this for some commands, and you can run gpg with gpg --no-use-agent, and it will proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `sudo` before the command solved it for some reason

Comment: -1: It's never a good idea to just randomly put `sudo` in front of commands.